# POST Json to API with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I want to post a JSON object I create in my service class and pass to the networkService.

This is my network service, but i get an error of

> Value of type '[String : Any]' has no member 'data'

on the line: `let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!`

```
    func request(json: [String:Any]) {

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
        (response) in
        print(response)
    }
}
```

The idea being I pass in my JSON when i call the func via the func parameter.

This is the JSON object passed in:

```
    func loginUser(data: Array<String>, deviceToken: String) {
    // create JSON
    let json = [ "login-email" : data[0],
                "login-password" : data[1],
                "login-secret" : "8A145C555C43FBA5",
                "devicetoken" : deviceToken
                ]

    networkManager.request(json: json)
}
```

Then I convert and send it to the API (urlString)

Any idea if/why this isnt working?

THanks

Updated revision:

```
func request(json: [String:Any]) {

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options:[])
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
            (response) in
            print(response)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to serialise and send JSON")
    }
}
```

update: added my code to make a call with completion question:

```
 func sendLoginRequest() {
        let userLogin = UserService.init(loginEmail: userEmail, loginPassword: userPassword, loginSecret: loginSecret, deviceToken: deviceToken)
        networkService.logUserIn(request: userLogin) { (<#JSON?#>, <#NSError?#>) in
            <#code#>
        }
    }
```

edit: Updated Payload Shot:

[image: API Payload Issue]

edit 2: mapping issue example:

```
init?(_ json: JSON) {
    // Map API Key from top level
    guard let apiKey = json["apikey"].string else { return nil }

    // Map User at user level
    guard let userDataArray = json["user"].array else {
        fatalError("user data array NOT FOUND")
    }
    print("USER DATA IS \(userDataArray)")
    // assign user 
    for child in userDataArray {
        guard let userID = child["id"].int,
            let userEmail = child["email"].string,
            let lastName = child["lastname"].string,
            let firstName = child["firstname"].string,
            let company = child["company"].string,
            let userImage = child["image"].string,
            let jobTitle = child["jobtitle"].string
            else { return nil
        }
    }

    // Assign to model properties
    self.apiKey = apiKey
    self.userEmail = userEmail
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.company = company
    self.userImage = userImage
    self.jobTitle = jobTitle
    self.userID = userID
}
```

Comment: `data(using: allowLossyConversion:)` that's a `String` object method. Not a Dictionary method (`json` is a `[String:Any]`). What you want instead is to use JSONSerialization.

Comment: thanks ill look into it and see if i can resolve this way

Comment: `let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options:[])` Or you could also use Alamofire that can manage parameters and will put them into the body.

Comment: I have updated the OP with new code, should this work? I didnt want to use Alamofire to handle them as I have so many services and calls the body will range widely so just wanted to pass a pre defined object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just show how I work with this.

You don't have to convert your parameters to JSON. It's code from Alamofire.

```
/// A dictionary of parameters to apply to a `URLRequest`.
public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]
```

Use this method instead of your:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: customHeaders)
```

**Try this:**
Instead of your `request.httpBody = jsonData` you can pass your `json` in `parameters`.

Your whole code will be:

```
func request(json: [String:Any]) {

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: json, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON {
        (response) in
        print(response)
    }

}
```

**If you are interested in my approach:**

```
func makePick(request: MakePickRequest, completionHandler: @escaping APICompletionHandler) {
        let parameters = request.converToParameters()
        Alamofire.request(Endpoints.makePick, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            self.handleResponse(response: response, completionHandler: completionHandler)
        }
    }
```

**Request:**

```
struct MakePickRequest: GeneralRequest {
    let eventId: Int64
    let sportId: String
    let pickType: PickType
    let betType: BetType
    let amount: Int

    func converToParameters() -> [String : String] {
        return ["event_id": String(eventId), "sport_id": sportId,
        "pick_type": pickType.rawValue, "bet_type": betType.rawValue,
        "amount": String(amount)]
    }
}
```

Structure with endpoints:

```
struct Endpoints {
    // Development baseURL
    static let baseURL = "http://myurl/"

    private static let apiVersion = "api/v1/"

    static var fullPath: String {
        return "\(baseURL)\(apiVersion)"
    }

    // MARK: - User endpoints (POST)
    static var login: String {
        return "\(fullPath)users/login"
    }

    static var signUp: String {
        return "\(fullPath)users/signup"
    }

    ...
}
```

Outside of any class (but import SwiftyJSON is obligatory):

```
typealias APICompletionHandler = (_ data: JSON?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void
```

Handle response:

```
private func handleResponse(response: DataResponse<Any>, completionHandler: APICompletionHandler) {
        self.printDebugInfo(response)
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            self.handleJSON(data: value, handler: completionHandler)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completionHandler(nil, error as NSError?)
        }
    }

 private func handleJSON(data: Any, handler: APICompletionHandler) {
        let json = JSON(data)
        let serverResponse = GeneralServerResponse(json)
        if (serverResponse?.status == .ok) {
            handler(serverResponse?.data, nil)
        } else {
            handler(nil, self.parseJsonWithErrors(json))
        }
    }
```

GeneralServerResponse (depends on your server API):

```
import SwiftyJSON

final class GeneralServerResponse {
    let data: JSON
    let status: Status

    init?(_ json: JSON) {
        guard let status = json["status"].int else {
            return nil
        }

        self.status = Status(status)
        self.data = json["data"]
    }

    enum Status {
        case ok
        case error
        case unauthorized

        init(_ input: Int) {
            if input >= 200 && input < 400 {
                self = .ok
            } else if input == 403 {
                self = .unauthorized
            } else {
                self = .error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My actual example of usage.**

This is outside:

```
func +=<K, V> ( left: inout [K : V], right: [K : V]) { for (k, v) in right { left[k] = v } }
```

Example of request:

```
func makePick(request: MakePickRequest, completionHandler: @escaping APICompletionHandler) {
        var parameters = ["auth_token": Preferences.getAuthToken()]
        parameters += request.converToParameters()
        manager.apiRequest(url: Endpoints.makePick, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            self.handleResponse(response: response, completionHandler: completionHandler)
        }
    }
```

SessionManager extension to add headers for all requests:

```
extension SessionManager {
    func apiRequest(url: URLConvertible, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: Parameters? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding, headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)  -> DataRequest {
        var customHeaders: HTTPHeaders = ["api-key" : "1wFVerFztxzhgt"]
        if let headers = headers {
            customHeaders += headers
        }
        return request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: customHeaders)
    }
}
```

In APIManager class:

```
private let manager: SessionManager

init() {
     manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
}
```

Call example:

```
apiClient.makePick(request: request) { data, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if let data = data {
            // data is a JSON object, here you can parse it and create objects
        }
    }
```

Example of class:

```
import SwiftyJSON

final class MyClass {
    let id: Int
    let username: String
    let parameter: Double

    init?(_ json: JSON) {
        guard let id = json["id"].int, let username = json["username"].string,
            let parameter = json["parameter"].double else {
                return nil
        }

        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.parameter = parameter
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, im getting 'Extra argument in call' when i use         Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: json, encoding: JSONEncoding.default){   out of interest, how do you handle a large number of end points? i see you reference a struct in your example?

Comment: I will add how I handle endpoints in my answer, wait a minute. Also, just try to put right arguments in this function. It will work for sure.

Comment: @jackdm, just pass first parameter urlString, it can be usual String.

Comment: @jackdm, now it will work. I forgot to add .responseJSON. Check my updated answer

Comment: thanks for this, do you have more details you can link to on your API structure? im am building mine and this looks like a great approach. when you pass response: response to the 'handle response' what kind of data type is it at this point?

Comment: I use SwiftyJson for handling JSON. typealias APICompletionHandler = (_ data: JSON?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void

Comment: much appreciated, and APICompletionHandler? ServerResponse? are they relevant

Comment: Added, check it.

Comment: really appreciate the help, this is a fantastic answer for anyone looking to structure an API!

Comment: just a question, you hardcode endpoint struct into the alamofire request, wouldnt it be better to pass this as a param so the func is reusable?

Comment: I have different cases, because sometimes I need to add other parameters. I update my answer and you will see.

Comment: @jackdm, I have a lot of functions and they take different params. And that's why there is no need to make a universal one and pass inside all the params. I can make a mistake.

Comment: thanks, so you have separate alamofire request funcs for each endpoint accesses with its own params? the rest of the functions in the class are shared for JSON callback handling for all the requests?

Comment: Yeah. I did it because I don't like making mistakes by passing wrong endpoints from outside or something like that. I just call the method by proper name and I know it will work as I want.

Comment: makes sense, and with your struct, when populating your model before convertToParameters, would you init an instance of it and pass in all the params needed at that point? for example the MakePickRequest struct creation

Comment: Yeah, I init it just before calling the method and pass all the needed params.

Comment: I tried different approaches, but this one works for me fine. Although this one isn't shortest measuring by lines of code.

Comment: thanks for the help, ill post back on this question if i have further related issue with the structure! youve been a great help :)

Comment: Thank you. Feel free to ask.

Comment: Quick question, when calling my network class's post method, how do i address the completion handler parameter? the request will obviously be the dictionary from the struct that creates it. But when making the call i need to provide the completion Handler Info? updated my OP with my call issue, the placeholders are showing at the moment in the handler

Comment: I will add to the end of my answer an example of calling a method.

Comment: Hi there, i had a query, my JSON is failing the sucess code check, but the payload seems fine, the "status" key reads sucess. which makes me think that something is happening to change the code from 200 to the word success in alamofire or swiftyjson? when i check in an API tool such as postman, i can see the code is 200. where as i cant see it anywhere in the request response in my app? Any ideas? as this is causing it to fail the switch statement and get an error enum assigned to it, due to the             guard let status = json["status"].int  returning nil..added screenshot to OP

Comment: 'status' is my custom parameter from server. It's different from HTTP status

Comment: oh, is there a way i can verify in this manner with my own HTTP status or is that not needed and i can delete these funcs? OP updated

Comment: You can delete this part and rely only on "case .success(let value):
            // Success code handling
        case .failure(let error):
            // Failure code handling
        }

Comment: thanks, i removed it, so how can i send the result of my success case (value) back to the calling func "manager.userServicesApiRequest(url: Endpoints.login, request: userLogin) { (data, error) in" as currently the if let isnt working so i assume its not returning

Comment: You can send this way: "case .success(let value): completionHandler(value, nil) case .failure(let error): completionHandler(nil, error as NSError?) }

Comment: i tried this before asking and it throws the error, Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'JSON?'

Comment: Yeah, sorry, change to this: "case .success(let value): let json = JSON(value) completionHandler(json, nil) case .failure(let error): completionHandler(nil, error as NSError?) }

Comment: do you advise mapping the JSON payload to the model in the viewModel? i assume i need to use swifty JSON here?

Comment: thanks and how do i handle if the keys are inside a parent such as 'user' ? will this mapping method return nil if there is no value for any dictionary key or just mark that single result as an empty string

Comment: You can use optionals "let parameter: Double?" and set "self.parameter = json["parameter"].double" after guard statement.

Comment: update my OP with my issue, its to do with accessing the child node, im getting scope issues etc

Comment: "userDataArray = json["user"].array" it's wrong, "user" is an object, not an array. Write something like that: "let user = json["user"]" and then "jobTitle = user["jobtitle"].string"